# Condition in queryParams angular2

Tags: angular, routeparams

```
<a href="#"
                        [routerLink]="[isTrue?'/location-1':'/location-2', '']"
                        [queryParams]="{id:loc.id,l:'loc'}">
```

Here when value of `isTrue` is `true`
**/location-1/?id=1&l=loc**

But when value of `isTrue` is `false`, I need
**/location-2/?id=1&l=loc2&idL=2**

So how do I modify parameter conditionally?

Answer (score 7):

Found solution,
we can also add ternary condition before object on `queryParams`.

```
[queryParams]="isTrue?{id:loc.id,l:'loc'}:{id:loc.id,l:'loc2',idL:loc.lId}"
```